# Near Analysis takes much longer in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, performance, proximity

I have a feature class of about 12 points, a feature class of hundreds of roads, and need to find the nearest road to each point. So the obvious solution ([Near tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001q000000)) takes about 20 seconds, and the results are fine.

When I try to put it in a script (see below), it takes *90 minutes*. Also, even though it doesn't crash/error, the results aren't right (the `NEAR_FID` and `NEAR_DIST` for each point are both "-1"). I'm running it within ArcMap as a tool, and the run time is all from the Near analysis (it quickly gets through importing the parameters, and then just thinks for a very long time).

I didn't use any of the optional parameters (radius, record angle, record xy, etc.) when running Near either manually or in the script. The data are the same.

Any ideas what is causing the trouble?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

pointsFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.AddMessage("Feature Class to be analyzed: " + pointsFC)

spatialRef = arcpy.Describe(pointsFC).spatialReference

outputWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
env.workspace = outputWorkspace
arcpy.AddMessage("Output Workspace " + outputWorkspace)

roadsFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
arcpy.AddMessage("Roads Layer: " + roadsFC)

# try to find the nearest road
try:
    in_feature = pointsFC
    near_feature = roadsFC
    arcpy.AddMessage("Finding nearest " + roadsFC + " to " + pointsFC)
    arcpy.Near_analysis(in_feature, near_feature)
except:
    arcpy.AddMessage(">> NEAR didn't work")
```

Comment: Are you running the NEAR command on datasets that reside on a a network drive?  See [Q: ArcGIS NEAR returns -1](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31196/arcgis-near-returns-1/32158#32158).

Comment: Yes, the data's on the network... and unfortunately moving it to a local version isn't a plausible solution for this application, so I guess I'll have to figure out some other approach :( Thanks for pointing me to the right symptom and finding the other related question!